# Xsl Fo: Place a block on last body column

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I would like to place a block always on the last column of my body.

My body is declared like this:

```
<fo:region-body column-count="3" column-gap="5mm" margin-top="25mm" margin-bottom="18mm" margin-right="10mm" margin-left="18mm" />
```

and I would like to always have a `<fo:block>` on the third column, even if there is nothing in the second.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Short answer is no. At the very least you would need to explain in details what you want if the content for all the columns ends just before the end of the third. Do you want a blank page with your block at the very bottom (assuming what you wish to insert does not fit on that page)? There is no way to do this without post-processing the intermediate output of the document *or* implementing a last-page template that may overlap your "block" that you wish to place at that location.

Comment: Would you considering answering your own question to close it (and deleting your comment above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround: I put my third column in a block-container with absolute position. Let's just hope that there is not enough content to fill the first two columns and overflow on the third... Thanks a lot! –